# CSS Portrait Media Query not detected on 720p and up phones

Tags: android, html, ios, css, media-queries

I created a website, but for some reason it isn't using my media queries properly.

Every css page has the following media queries:

```
@media all and (orientation: portrait) {}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 1366px) {}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 720px) and (max-width: 1365px) {}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 719px) {}
@media all and (orientation: landscape) and (max-width: 479px) {}
```

For some reason though neither on my OnePlus 3T nor on my girlfirends iPhone SE (tried in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera Mini) does it use the "potrait" media queries in portrait mode.

Comment: looking at this code it's difficult to solve your problem, try including some more information

Comment: The rest of the information shouldn't matter and differs based on witch page you are viewing. Here is the website http://rsivanova.com